# AWS EC2: how to get a data transfer breakdown per instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I have an AWS account with some small instances on it.
Is there a way to see the amount of data which has been transfetered (in/out) per instance?

Thanks
Dmi

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the instances are still running, you can do this using the free basic monitoring that Amazon provides via [CloudWatch](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/).

> For Amazon EC2 instances, Amazon CloudWatch Basic Monitoring collects
>   and reports metrics for CPU utilization, **data transfer**, and disk usage
>   activity from each Amazon EC2 instance at a five-minute frequency.

To access the monitor data for an EC2 instance, select it in the [AWS Management Console](https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2) and click the "Monitoring" tab in the lower panel.  You can click any of the charts (e.g. "Max Network In") to get a larger version, with some drop-downs to control the time window.

Note that the data is only kept for two weeks.

Comment: Is there a way to get sum of data tansferred per hour, per day etc?

Comment: Note, that this shows "internal" data transfer too, not to the outside world :(

Comment: @antimatter Looking at 2023 console, there is. Under "Graphed Metrics" section, select "Sum" and time period you want. Optionally you can download the metrics in csv and do the maths on your own